# PHP does not send all queries to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very strange problem: My PHP snippet is supposed to send multiple queries to a MySQL database. However, the last query is not sent. And there is no error. Even if I intentionally try to send invalid SQL. It just doesn't happen anything. The Apache error log is not showing any errors either. Please see my snippet below:

```
$mysql = "INSERT INTO office (office_Name,street,postcode,city,mail) VALUES ('$office_name', '$street', '$postcode', '$city', '$mail')";
//works:
$sqlcon->query($mysql);

//works:
$office_id = mysqli_insert_id($sqlcon);

$mysql = "CALL get_order_code('foobar',@x);"; 
//works:
$result = $sqlcon->query($mysql);
$code = $result->fetch_object()->ordercode;
$result->close();

$hash = sha1($code);

$mysql = "INSERT INTO orders (office_ID, amount, order_code) VALUES ('$office_id', '$amount', '$hash')";
//does not work:
$sqlcon->query($mysql);
```

Comment: I see this question a lot. Please read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: doesn't look like you have error handling in the code though.. which is probably why its not getting logged

Comment: For the love of god, do **not** insert variables directly into SQL queries! Escape them first, or use prepared statements.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: At the moment it is very secure as it is not working at all. Please. This is a stripped example and not a production system. @Fred-ii- I have added those lines, yet there are no errors. The script just runs as if the last line just wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are closing the connection before the last query. $result->close(); should be moved below $sqlcon->query($mysql);.

Comment: `$result->close()` is closing the result set, not the connection

Answer (score 0):

You should use [stmt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for inserting, it works like this:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (office_ID, amount, order_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param ("iis", $office_id, $amount, $hash)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: It does not matter if I try to insert, provide any other query or even invalid SQL code. It just does do anything. No effect on the database, no error. Just nothing.

Comment: @sofpeter your approach is just wrong, you should always use stmt prepared statements. besides there's no error handling in your code, that's why you're seeing nothing. try adding `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the beginning of the code, and tell me if you're still not seeing any warnings.

Comment: Again. This is not a production system. This is just minimal code to figure out why the hell this last query doesn't do anything. So to figure out why PHP just won't send the query my approach is just perfect. And as I said: there are no errors.

Comment: production or not. you should always use the prepared statement way because it helps you debug better, and it's the right way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: please at least try my code, and tell me if it's still not working. I'm trying to get some reputation in here.